# How to implement search bar with JSON data using swift?

Tags: ios, json, tableview

I am using below JSON POST Call, I am trying to append JSON array to collection view search bar array. I tried my best but I can't able to get solutions.

```
do {
    if let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data) as? [[String: Any]] {
        for item in json {
            let id = item["id"]!
            let category = item["category"]!
            //print(id,category)

            if let people = item["People"] as? [[String:String]] {
                for person in people {
                    //print(person["name"]!, person["age"]!)
                    self.nameArray.append(person["name"]!)
                    self.ageArray.append(person["age"]!)
                    print(self.nameArray)
                }
            }
        }
    }
} catch let parseError {
    print("parsing error: \(parseError)")
    let responseString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
    print("raw response: \(responseString!)")
}
```

Comment: you can use **Decodable**

Comment: Sure I will do it. but provide me some lines of code examples. I am very new for this @Sh_Khan

Comment: @JUJU Please read and study these two sources about `Codable`: [Swift blog: Working with JSON in Swift](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=37) and [Ultimate Guide to JSON Parsing with Swift 4](https://benscheirman.com/2017/06/swift-json/)